# Understanding static initialization

Tags: c++, static-initialization

I wrote this code:

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

constexpr int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}

int bar(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}

int a = bar(1,2); // Dynamic initialization. This brace-or-equal initializer 
                  // contains expression which is not a constant expression
int main()
{ 
    a = foo(3,4); // Constexpr function invocation. Static initialization.
    std::cout << a; // 12
}
```

This program outputs `12`. I expected that `2` will be outputted. Because every Static Initialization is performed before Dynamic Initialization. I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment is not initialisation. The assignment from `foo(3,4)` happens after `main` begins (which is after the initialisation from `bar(1,2)`), and before printing the value.

Comment: Is it possible to initialize a variable twice at all?

Comment: @St.Antario: No. Objects are only initialised once.

Comment: Is initialization the same concept as definition?

Comment: @St.Antario: They're related, but separate, concepts. The definition of a variable allocates storage for it. Initialisation creates a valid object within that storage. (A dynamic object, created by `new`, is initialised by the new-expression, but doesn't have a definition. A local static variable has a definition, but might never be initialised if the program never reaches the definition.)

Comment: @St.Antario It's possible, but you're not likely to do it accidentally, and in most cases, it would be an error if you did.  Still, `new (&a) int( 42 );` would do it (although you could only see the difference with class types).

Comment: Mike: Normally, allocation and initialization are bound, both in variable definition and in a `new` expression.  You can separate them, however, by allocating with the `operator new` function (or `malloc`, or by defining a `char[]`), and then using placement `new`.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is not declared `constexpr` so it cannot be initialized via a `constexpr` expression. In the scenario you present, the second "initialization" is in fact a dynamic assignment.

Comment: Can you provide a quote from Standard which describes what you write.

Comment: The first sentence is wrong: anything can be initialised by a constant expression. `a` not being `constexpr` (or just `const`) means that its value can't be used in a constant expression.